# Instance variable not passed into view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

**EDIT: Solved. Solution:**

Include
`gem 'rabl'` and `gem 'oj'` in your gemfile along with `gem rabl-rails`

For some reason, my instance variable isn't being passed into the view (I'm using Rabl).

Here's the relevant code:

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def index
    @articles = Article.original.last(100)
  end

  def after
    @articles = Article.where("id > #{params[:id]}")
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

show.json.rabl

```
object @article

attributes :id, :headline, :source, :link

attributes :similar_articles => :similar
```

The error:

```
RuntimeError in Articles#show

Showing /Users/chintanparikh/Dropbox/Projects/Current/article_aggregator/app/views/articles/show.json.rabl where line #2 raised:

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your Rails version? Rails 4 uses strong params that requires you to write a param method in the controller.

Comment: 3.2.13. Doesn't look like params is the issue (read my comment on Johns answer)

Answer (score 0):

The ID you're using to look up the record does not match one within your database.

Check what `params[:id]` is evaluating to and ensure that you can locate a record using that value.

Comment: If I throw a debugger at the bottom of the show method and check the value of @article, it's a valid Article.

Comment: Then something bad is happening in your view. Can you debug `@article` in the view? According to your error, `@article` is `nil` in your view.

Comment: Yup ```@article``` is definitely nil in my view. Strange thing is, if I add :html to the responds_to, and create a show.html.erb that prints out @article, it works fine, so I think it might be rabl that's acting up.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, you need these three lines in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rabl-rails'
gem 'rabl'
gem 'oj'
```

Before, I only had rabl-rails, and I assume that was causing the problem.

Comment: I would submit the missing gem dependencies to the rabl team as a bug then. I would expect those to be included automatically if required for things to work.

Comment: I don't think actually fixes the issue with rabl-rails but simply uses the regular (slower) rabl gem in its place.